# Send email from any email account to any recipient

Tags: c#, email, sendmail, send

Could you please tell me is it possible to send email in C# from **any** email account to **any** recipient? I mean smtp server for both is different.

I read a lot of articles about that, tried different approaches but no effect.
Using one approach I get an error "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Must be local recipient". It means that sender and recipient should be from the same smtp server.

The other approach was from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26663/Email-Sender).
Very often email isn't sent to some recipient, sometimes it is being sent 4 times instead of one. This isnt reliable for all email addresses.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it will depend on your SMTP server and how it allows you to send mail. In my project I can send `from` anyone, `to` anyone.

Comment: You probably should ask this question on serverfault.com as it is not really related to programming but rather to security and SMTP servers/gateways.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you can send from any account to any account, *provided that the SMTP servers let you*. You can't connect to a random SMTP server and expect to send mail from that server to an address that's on some other server. Such a thing is called an open relay, and is (or at least used to be) the source of much spam.

Typically, if you want to use an SMTP server to send mail, you have to log in (authenticate) with your user name and password. That way, ISPs aren't unwittingly contributing to the spam problem. Once you're logged in, you can tell the SMTP server to relay mail from you to somebody who has an account at another server.

If you want to send mail to name@somewhere.com and you can't log in to an SMTP server that will do the relay for you, then you need to connect directly to the SMTP server that serves the domain somewhere.com. Even then, it might not accept mail from you, depending on how it's set up. SMTP servers will often to a reverse lookup to see if your IP address matches the IP address of the SMTP server that's known (by the DNS system) to handle mail for yourname@yourdomain.com.

The SMTP support in C# will allow you to connect to a server, log in, and send mail. Whether the server lets you do that is another thing entirely.

Comment: C# --> .NET Framework.  Like saying English will allow you to write a letter from anyone and send it to anyone ;)

Comment: Thank you Jim for your response. You say that I can use an SMTP server to send mail, I have to log in (authenticate) with my user name and password. Do you mean that I have to create some local SMTP server (localhost) which will get only my messages and redirect them to different recipients?

Comment: @EduardBagrov: I'm not saying what you need to do, because you haven't said what you want to do. You wanted to know if it's possible to send mail with C#. The answer is yes. The bigger problem is dealing with SMTP servers. You'll get better answers about that over on serverfault.com.

Comment: I asked the question "If anybody knows how do that (sending mail from any box to any recipient), please let me know", but just noticed that for some reason it was deleted by Alexei Levenkov. Anyway thank you, I didn't know about serverfault.com, there is much to investigate.